# rails assets pipeline: Getting the error No route matches [GET] "/bootstrap-tag/css/bootstrap-tag.css" in development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to add **bootstrap-tag**(https://github.com/fdeschenes/bootstrap-tag) to my rails app. I followed the below steps

1) added the bootstrap-tag folder to vendor/assets. 
Now the path to the css file is ****vendor/assets/bootstrap-tag/css/bootstrap-tag.css.****

2)  checked my assets pipeline paths with **Rails.application.config.assets.paths** and i can see the path **../vendor/assets/bootstrap-tag.**

3)In application.css i added ***=require css/bootstrap-tag.css**(This method worked for all other similar plugins i added to rails)

But when i loaded my app in chrome and checked the source, the link is showing up as **"/assets/../bootstrap-tag/css/bootstrap-tag.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet"**

when i click on it it gives me **No route matches [GET] "/bootstrap-tag/css/bootstrap-tag.css"**

The above steps worked for all other similar plugins i used, except this one. please help

Comment: Should it be require `bootstrap-tag.css` instead of `bootstrap.css`? Is that a typo?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. i corrected it. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to `*=require bootstrap-tag/css/bootstrap-tag.css`

Or if you prefer a more conventional take, you can put your css file as `vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-tag.css` and I don't think you need to do any additional require statements if it's in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply taylor. I tried the first change you mentioned.that didnt work. The second option does work. But my app has lot of javascript plugins like this and i will be nice to put them in separate folders :). i have installed font-awesome the exact same way i mentioned above and it works fine. lets see if someone else have a different opinion. else i will accept your answer.

Comment: I finally figured it out. all i had to do is move the *=require bootstrap-tag.css right after other bootstrap css files calls. weird. something to do with the order of calling the css files